# Getting Error: TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Here I'm trying to create new array based on the size provided dynamically

Why this is happening?

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  // Break it up.
  var updatedarr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      updatedarr[i][j] = arr[i];
    }
  }
  return updatedarr;
}
chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);
```

Comment: You have to create `updatedarr[i]` in the outer loop before the inner loop.

Comment: `updatedarr[i]` should be defined as `array`

Comment: @gowtham, Refer the answer provided below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chunk your array by,

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var updatedarr=[]; 
  for(var i =0;i<arr.length ;i+=size) {
    updatedarr.push([]);
    //pushing the array which gonna contain the chunk.
    for(var j=i;j<i+size;j++) { // run loop from i to i+size ex: 0->2 when i = 0.
     //picking the last chunk array and pushing the values
      updatedarr[updatedarr.length - 1].push(arr[j]);
    }
  }
  return updatedarr; 
}

chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d","e","f","g"], 2);
```

And the output would be,

```
[["a","b"],["c","d"],["e","f"],["g"]]
```

As per the new requirement of you in your comment, you have to use break when ever you hit with an undefined.

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var updatedarr=[]; 
  for(var i =0;i<arr.length ;i+=size) {
    updatedarr.push([]);
    for(var j=i;j<i+size;j++) {
      if(typeof arr[j] == "undefined") break;
      updatedarr[updatedarr.length - 1].push(arr[j]);
    }
  }
  return updatedarr; 
}

 chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4);
```

OUTPUT:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: would you please explain me above code

Comment: @gowtham Given some comments, Hope that would help. For more details you can put a break point and traverse through the flow of the code.

Comment: the above code is not satisfying the chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4) should return [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]

Comment: @gowtham See the updated post. Just added a break by checking the condition.